# Using Docker for windows to volume-mount a windows drive into a Linux container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers, docker-machine, linux-containers

I'm using Docker Desktop for Windows and I want to find where the volumes are created by Docker, in a Linux container?

Has anyone been able to perform the volume mounting that I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you're just trying to mount a windows path to a Linux based container, here's an example using the basic `docker run` command, and a Docker Compose example as well:

```
docker run -d --name qbittorrent -v '/mnt/f/Fetched Media/Unsorted:/downloads' -v '/mnt/f/Fetched Media/Blackhole:/blackhole' linuxserver/qbittorrent
```

This example shares the `f:\Fetched Media\Unsorted` and `f:\Fetched Media\Blackhole` folders on the Windows host to the container; and within the Linux container you'd see the files from those Windows folders in their respective Linux paths shown to the right of the colon(s).

i.e. the `f:\Fetched Media\Unsorted` folder will be in the `/downloads` folder in the Linux container.

*First though, make sure you've shared those Windows folders within the Docker Desktop settings area in the GUI.

---

**Update for WSL(2)**:

You don't need to specifically share the Windows folder paths; that's only needed when *not* using WSL.

---

**Update**:

This seems to be a popular answer, so I thought I'd also include a Docker Compose version of the above example, for the sake of thoroughness (includes how to set a path as read-write (`rw`), or read-only (`ro`)):

```
qbittorrent:
  image: 'linuxserver/qbittorrent:latest'
  volumes:
    - '/mnt/f/Fetched Media/Unsorted:/downloads:rw'
    - '/mnt/f/Fetched Media/Blackhole:/blackhole:rw'
    - '/mnt/e/Logs/qbittorrent:/config/logs:rw'
    - '/opt/some-local-folder/you-want/read-only:/some-folder-inside-container:ro'
```

Comment: I scoured the internet everywhere for this. Thank you so much. Really surprised it's not in Docker documentation

Comment: is it possible to do this with a shared network drive? when i have tried the resulting mapped folder comes up empty

Comment: @liam Loaded question! lol. Take a look here: https://forums.docker.com/t/mounted-windows-share-doesnt-show-contents-within-docker-container/100343

Comment: From a clean Windows 11 install of Docker Desktop for Windows and WSL 2 with no distro like Ubuntu installed, it didn't recognize /mnt. Starting straight from the drive letter worked: /f/Fetched Media/Unsorted

Answer (score 10):

I'm not certain why this was needed, but in the event someone else runs into this problem: I had to put the entire volume declaration in double quotes as follows

```bash
docker run -d --name qbittorrent -v "/mnt/f/Fetched Media/Unsorted:/downloads" -v "/mnt/f/Fetched Media/Blackhole:/blackhole" linuxserver/qbittorrent
```

Otherwise, J. Scott Elblein's answer worked perfectly!

Comment: You're correct; sometimes it helps to extend the last quote all the way to the end so the entire string is quoted. I usually find this to be necessary if there's a strange character in one of the paths, like a dot, in the case of a hidden folder.

Comment: Note: to avoid any possible confusion, I just updated my answer to reflect your answer as well. :)