# Get access to folder at host machine from docker container

Tags: docker, jenkins, wix, containers

I have a docker container with Jenkins installed on it.
I installed the Wix toolset plugin to create CI/CD pipeline for MSI packages

I need to provide a path to a folder at host machine

I tried it like this, but docker don't see the path

[image]

I tried to execute this command

```
docker jenkins-master  run -v C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin
```

But have same stuff. Where can be a problem?

**UPDATE**

I tried to do it like this

```
docker run -d --name jenkins-master -v "/c/Program Files (x86)/WiX Toolset v3.11/bin":/downloads jenkins-master
```

And get this error

> Unable to find image 'jenkins-master:latest' locally
> docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for jenkins-master, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
> See 'docker run --help'.

Here is a list of my containers

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Docker for windows to volume-mount a windows drive into a Linux container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60916317/using-docker-for-windows-to-volume-mount-a-windows-drive-into-a-linux-container)

Comment: Updated question @Septem151

Answer (score 0):

While it is possible to add a volume to a running container on Linux (see this [article](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/01/13/docker-mount-dynamic-volumes/)), I don't know of any way to do it on Windows, especially since Linux containers do nor run directly on the host Windows machine, but rather in a virtual machine running Linux. This virtual machine typically has acces only to `C:\Users` (mounted as `/c/Users`) and not to `C:\Program Files (x86)`.

Your bes bet would be to edit the VM to give it access to `C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11` (exact method depends on whether you use Docker Toolbox or Docker for Windows), destroy your Jenkins container and recreate with with the directory properly mounted.

That being said I do not believe that a Linux installation of Jenkins will be able to use a Windows Wix binary. The best solution would be to turn your Windows host into a Jenkins slave that runs the whole build.