# Mounting Docker directory to host directory doesn't work

Tags: python, docker, containers, volume

I'm currently trying to mount a Docker container directory to my local host directory. My local folder has the path `C:/Users/lp/local_env-Returns/` and has the following files: `cmi_forecast_script.py` , `Dockerfile`, `requirements.txt` , `.dockerignore` and `sales_data.xlsx`. I'm running the Python script when I run the Docker container of the Dockerfile. This creates a csv_file in my Docker container. The path of the csv_file in the container is `/cmi_forecast_script/7789-10033.csv`. Now I want that I have the csv-file also in my local-directory. I already tried to mount the two paths with `docker run -v /Users/lp/local_env-Returns/:/cmi_forecast_script/ <image name>`. But then I get: `python: can't open file 'cmi_forecast_script.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`. Where is the problem?

PS: I also tried `docker run -v /Users/lp/local_env-Returns/:/cmi_forecast_script/cmi_forecast_script.py <image name>` but then I get another error which is too long to post here.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
WORKDIR /cmi_forecast_script
COPY . /cmi_forecast_script
RUN adduser -u 5678 --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser && chown -R appuser /cmi_forecast_script
USER appuser
CMD ["python", "cmi_forecast_script.py"]`
```

Comment: Are you on Windows? The path you're mounting `/Users/...` is not the same as you say above `C:/Users/...`. Check it out

Comment: Yes, I am on Windows, but when adding C:/... it also doesn`t work. I think because of the : after the C

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60916317/using-docker-for-windows-to-volume-mount-a-windows-drive-into-a-linux-container if solves your mounting issue and then update

Comment: So now I tried `docker run -v "/C/Users/lp/local_env-Returns/:/cmi_forecast_script/" localenvreturns`, but I'm getting the same error

Comment: Your queue for edit is full. Please edit your question in a more readable way and then let me know if I can help. Also check if `local_env-Returns` is a directory or a file.

Comment: local_env-Returns is a folder

Comment: I think the issue is with your `Dockerfile` `COPY` command. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46309423/dockerfile-copy-from-a-windows-file-system-to-a-docker-container. You cannot